# React Router 4, LINK and ROUTE on different layout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

It's my first time I trying reactJS. I'm using AdminLTE and trying to change content from sidebar navigation. This my code:

menu:

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu tree" id="menu"></ul>
```

content:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="box box-primary">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Quick Example</h3>
                </div>
                <div id="master"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

master.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import createRoutes from './routes';

    const routes = createRoutes();

    ReactDOM.render(
        routes,
        document.getElementById('master')
    );
```

menu.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link} from 'react-router-dom';


class Menu extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <Link to={"/laravel-react/public/dashboard/welcome"}><i className="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Welcome</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link to={"/laravel-react/public/dashboard/about"}><i className="fa fa-circle-o"></i>About</Link>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Menu/>, document.getElementById('menu'));
```

routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Welcome from './Welcome'
import About from './About'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

const createRoutes = () => (

    <Router>
        <ul>
            <Route exact path="/laravel-react/public/dashboard/welcome" component={Welcome}/>
            <Route exact path="/laravel-react/public/dashboard/about" component={About}/>
        </ul>
    </Router>
);

export default createRoutes;
```

The problem is when I click link from sidebar, URL changed but content not changed. Except if I refresh the page or i click back on browser, content will changed. I'm not sure if it's right or wrong way, because I read many tutorial where `<route>` and `<link>` located inside same `<Router>`.

Answer (score 2):

You only need one tag in your html where you will render your whole React application. To have `Links` working you need to put them under one `BrowserRouter`:

**Menu:**

```
export default class Menu extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to={"/laravel-react/public/dashboard/welcome"}>
            <i className="fa fa-circle-o" /> Welcome
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to={"/laravel-react/public/dashboard/about"}>
            <i className="fa fa-circle-o" />About
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

**routes:**

```
const MyRoutes = () => (
  <ul>
    <Route
      exact
      path="/laravel-react/public/dashboard/welcome"
      component={Welcome}
    />
    <Route
      exact
      path="/laravel-react/public/dashboard/about"
      component={About}
    />
  </ul>
);

export default MyRoutes;
```

**Master:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import createRoutes from './routes';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Menu from 'path/to/Menu';
import MyRoutes from 'path/to/MyRoutes';

const routes = createRoutes();

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Menu />
        <MyRoutes />
      <div>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('master')
);
```

Everything is rendered to `master` tag as one React component.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I've try your code, but it make menu move to content layout, from https://prnt.sc/jdqvj8 to https://prnt.sc/jdqvem. And when I click, content still not changed.

Comment: These are styling issues that you need to solve like would normally with HTML and CSS. Not sure why Links don't work.

Comment: Hey, now the content are changed, maybe caused by cache. And about menu that moving to `content` layout, I'm not sure because styling issues, I think this because everything is rendered to `master` tag. So, `menu` will displayed in `content` layout, not in sidebar. `menu` should be rendered at here `<ul class="sidebar-menu tree" id="menu"></ul>`.

Comment: @kresek You would then have two applications within one html page. Trust me you only need one tag and ret can be accomplished with html and css. Trust me you will save yourself a lot of trouble this way.

Comment: Yes, I'll try it later, but for now I'm still curious how solve this problem. No problem, this is not for my project, it's just my first reactJS learning :D. Thank you for your help, Tomasz!